# thread safety of hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a HashTable.

Now as hashtable is thread safe, so whenever i add something to list within hashtable also tread safe?

eg

```
if hmp is my map

 hmp.get(0).add(something)

 hmp.get(0).remove(0)
```

Are these operations thread safe?

Comment: It depends on the list you stored inside your HashTable. Remember that `add` is called on the object stored inside the hash table, so this object must be thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

No, absolutely not. The thread-safety of the individual operations on the hashtable don't affect the thread-safety of what you put *into* the hashtable at all. So if you put an `ArrayList<T>` reference into the hashtable for example, that's not threadsafe, so you shouldn't use it from multiple threads without synchronization if any of those threads will be modifying the data.

Comment: so if i use HashTable<Integer,BlockingQueue>  then i think my problem is solved.Can you please comment?

Comment: @akshay: Yes, that should be okay. Do you definitely need `HashTable` rather than (say) `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Answer (score -2):

```
   package legacyCLasses;
   import java.util.*;
   public class HashTable_With_Enumeration implements Runnable
   {
    Hashtable<Integer,String> htobj=new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
    static int count=1;
    public void run() 
    {
            this.htobj.put(10,"ABC");
            this.htobj.put(200,"PQR");
            this.htobj.put(1,"JKL");
            this.dis();
    }
    void dis()
    {
        try
        {
            Enumeration<String> eobj=this.htobj.elements();
            while(eobj.hasMoreElements())
            {
                System.out.print(eobj.nextElement());
                if(count%2!=0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\t\t\t\t");
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    count++;
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashTable_With_Enumeration heobj1=new HashTable_With_Enumeration();
        HashTable_With_Enumeration heobj2=new HashTable_With_Enumeration();     
        Thread t=new Thread(heobj1,"HashTable_Thread1");
        Thread t2=new Thread(heobj2,"HashTable_Thread2");
        try
        {
            System.out.print("\n"+t.getName()+" Values \t"+t2.getName()+ "Values     
              \n");                     
            t.start();  
            Thread.sleep(500);          
            t2.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question?